# Is there a way I can clone my input fields and save the data during each duplication?

Tags: javascript

With JS, I populate the form with a group of fields which I then either duplicate or remove.
As I duplicate the fields, my intention is to have the input values stored in an object.
When I click on the plus button, the fields duplicate, but the values entered disappear and the data is not captured.

JS

```js
var html = `<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Field Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-name" placeholder="Field Name" name="field_name">
    </div>
    <span>-</span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Field Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-name" placeholder="Field Type" name="field_type">
    </div>

    <span>-</span>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Field Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-name" placeholder="Default value" name="field_default">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    <span class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">-</span>
    </span>
    <span class="add_button btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
        <span class="add_button glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>`;

var crud_name = document.querySelector('.crud_name') // this is the first input box
var field_group = document.querySelector('.form-container')

// load the first group of fields to the DOM
field_group.innerHTML += html

var fields = []; // this will store all the database/crud fields
var plus_button = document.querySelector('.add_button')

/**
 * The event is used when the user clicks on the plus button
 * The event is on the form itself, but the target is the plus button
 */
plus_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if(e.target.classList.contains('add_button')) {

        let inputs = e.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll('input')
        var obj = {};
        Array.from(inputs).forEach(input => {
       

obj[input.name]= input.value;
    })

    fields.push(obj);
    console.log(fields);

    field_group.innerHTML += html
    // field_group.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)

}
})
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <form action="" method="post" id="crud_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter CRUD name. Eg: Task" class="crud_name form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-container"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save_crud">Save</button>
  </form>
```

How can I store the data each time I click to add the new group of inputs?
I tried to mimic this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gp6xjx?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your question. If you don't want the inputs to disappear replace the last `field_group.innerHTML += html` by `field_group.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)`.

Comment: @B Plit the solution does not work.
I will also edited my question because the click I assume must be on the plus button, and the HTML I getting added to the DOM a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

Your button type is submit, so it submits the form when its clicked and the browser will refresh the page.  Change the button type to type="button" and the form wont submit when you click the button. Then you can save the form input values to your javascript objects and add the new extra fields in to the page with javascript as well.

Comment: I just edited my question.
I think that the clicks must happen on the span tag so I cannot use submit.

Comment: Part of your issue is you have multiple form inputs with the same ID, you can't do that, each ID must be unique, its the whole reason the ID field is used, for unique identifiers. I see what you're trying to accomplish (I think), separate the ++ span and - span so that these do not get re-inserted with field_group.innerHTML += html   Just have those buttons already on the page when it loads so that clicking + doesn't insert another class='add_button' to your form because the code as you have it written will break if you do that.